# Google Drive android API sharing issue

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Is it possible to share file created at google drive with specific google users using android drive API? It is said (http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ru/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html) that "Google Drive API offers specialized functionality... including access to metadata and sharing features". However, I couldn't find any means to share file using android drive API. There's no hint in API documentation about how to do it. If it matters, I'm going to share file stored in AppFolder of my app (other users of the app should be able to access it).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app?

Comment: It could be great, but the link is about javascript( thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing is not currently supported in the Android-specific API (sorry for the confusing wording in the blog post.)

You can fallback to the web API to do sharing (e.g, modifying [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions)).  To use the web API, use [DriveId.getResourceId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#getResourceId%28%29).

However, files that are in the AppFolder are special.  Items in that folder cannot currently be shared.  They are only visible to your app and the specific user.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll have to use not hidden files to share data. Each user of the group will share one xml file containing "messages" for other users.

Comment: But I have a problem with getting file Id from `DriveId.getResourceId()`. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553989/how-to-get-google-drive-file-id