# GoogleDrive SDK - get resourceId on upload finish

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want get the resourceId after upload but it's returning null. Can you help me to get this value?
Thanks in advance.

```
Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), driveIdResult.getDriveId())
    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull final DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult) {
            if (driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                String driveId = driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId().toString();
                //return this:
                //DriveId:CAESHDBCeEc0ZnI0YkQ0ZVZRa1E1YTNVMFVtUTRkRlUY1GcgsPT0w7xTKAA=

                String resourceId = driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId().getResourceId();
                //null
                //but I want something like this: 0BxG4fr4bD4eVQXRjbTRBV2RMUHc
                uploadCallBack.onFinish(true, resourceId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {
            uploadCallBack.onFinish(false, null);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can follow this user's suggestion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553269/1045199

Judging from your code, `DriveId.toString()` returns something useful you can use to compare it to the event. I'd say:

- create a map of `<String, UploadCallback>`, using `DriveId.toString` as keys
- setup and register a `DriveEventService` with `onCompletion()`
- inside the upload result callback, call `file.addChangeSubscription(getGoogleApiClient())` so that you will get notifications in your `DriveEventService`
- from inside `onCompletion()` you can get a DriveId to use for `Map.get()` by invoking `event.getDriveId()`

I didn't test it, but it should work, at least in theory.

---

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555159/1045199 describes a very similar approach. Remember to call `setNotifyOnCompletion(true)` when you build your `ExecutionOptions`.